# Why don't the lines before join() method printing prior to start of 'joined' thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know when join method is called inside one thread, then that thread must wait until 'joined Thread' terminates. But If there is more code before calling join() method - what will happen? I post my code and confusion in the following code:

```
class MyJoinThread extends Thread {

   public static Thread myMain;

   public void run() {
     for(int i = 0; i< 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("I am loop");
     }
     try {
        myMain.join();
     }
     catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }

     for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.println("I am "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }
  }
}

class MyJoinMainThread {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
       MyJoinThread.myMain = Thread.currentThread();
       MyJoinThread th = new MyJoinThread();
       th.start();

       for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
          System.out.println("I am " + Thread.currentThread());
      }
   }


}
```

Given Output is:

```
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am loop
I am loop
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
```

Why the output is not like this?

```
   I am loop
   I am loop
   I am Thread[main,5,main]
   .....
   I am Thread[main,5,main]
   I am Thread-0
   ..
   I am Thread-0
   I am Thread-0
```

I include a loop before calling join() method on main Thread. Why this lines are not printed before main Thread starts to execute? Because that loop is called before the call of join() method.

Comment: is this system.out + err ? ;) ...how to join the "main thread" !?? `System.exit(int);`? :) ...No, seriously: You cannot rely on anything *before* join, but after join you can be sure main is "completed"..

Comment: main() doesn't have to stop when you call th.start();  your code is probably not "deterministic".  read about context switching

Comment: @AbdulAhad - Abdul Ahad - It is true, in this code which Thread will start first, we can not assume. It might be main thread first, or it might be "MyJoinThread" first. But one thing must happen, that is when myMain.join() calls, "MyJoinThread" must wait for the termination of "main Thread".

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get when run program (and the order of `I am loop` and `I am Thread[main,5,main]` changes after each run):

```
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am loop
I am loop
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread[main,5,main]
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
I am Thread-0
```

Since there is no synchronization (and no happens-before relation https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/happens-before.html) between `System.out.println("I am " + Thread.currentThread());` in main thread and `System.out.println("I am loop");` in second thread, there is no guaranteed order of those statements in console.

And actual order depends on scheduler and on how much time will it take to spawn a new thread by JVM on your PC.